# Calculate the mean of column that contains NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, missing-data

I have:

```
name   nationality  income 
Joe    American     30000
Mira   Iraqi        NaN
Maria  Spanish      87000
```

I would like to calculate the mean of the income column and replace the missing value NaN with that mean.

When I write:

```
mean = df["income"].mean()
df["income"].replace(np.nan,mean)
```

I get:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

I tried

```
mean(skipna=True)
```

to ignore the NaN from the mean calculation, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
df['income'] = df['income'].fillna((df['income'].mean()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be working. When I try it with my dummy dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'income': [20, np.nan, 20, 10]})
mean = df.income.mean()
df.income.replace(np.nan, mean)
```

You can also try the following:

```
df.loc[df.income.isnull(), 'income'] = df.income.mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.fillna()` to replace all nan values like this:

```
df.income = df.income.fillna((df.income.mean()))
```